# Why is my NSLog information overwriting itself/getting cutoff?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

Consider the following code:

```
- (void)printAssetData {    
    PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *allAssets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:nil];

    for (PHAsset *asset in allAssets) {        
        NSLog(@"localIdentifier:%@, creationDate:%@, pixelWidth:%ld, pixelHeight:%ld", asset.localIdentifier, asset.creationDate, asset.pixelWidth, asset.pixelHeight);
    }
}
```

When I run this on my personal device (with several thousand pictures/videos), this is the output:

```
2018-01-08 11:30:43.496875-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:D2349261-B3DF-445D-97C5-17D0B0DEEE37/L0/001, creationDate:Thu Dec 22 17:08:50 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.496925-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:9F14665C-0E43-4BE3-BEC5-DE401FE2131D/L0/001, creationDate:Thu Dec 22 17:09:42 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.496950-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:746158A9-C6D6-4F6B-83EA-2B3B2F2CEF5B/L0/001, creationDate:Fri Dec 23 01:36:44 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.496973-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:301A7472-89BD-4571-9672-AF8F49E97959/L0/001, creationDate:Fri Dec 23 01:36:48 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.496996-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:29149949-9F72-4D5F-8CE4-FC22EAEE7661/L0/001, creationDate:Fri Dec 23 01:37:25 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
ly[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:6B4B893A-E517-452D-972C-82354D93EA1C/L0/001, creationDate:Fri Dec 23 01:53:12 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.500454-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:878CE7A8-E218-452B-AF0F-8F6589347235/L0/001, creationDate:Sun Dec 25 20:19:46 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.500488-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:9F4B5249-C3B1-42C1-836C-64A83B485641/L0/001, creationDate:Thu Dec 29 00:02:47 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.500513-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:5A812FE1-61ED-4026-859E-2439795442C3/L0/001, creationDate:Thu Dec 29 13:53:50 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
2018-01-08 11:30:43.500536-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:278508D3-14AE-477C-92E4-7711CB2EC4D8/L0/001, creationDate:Thu Dec 29 16:04:29 2011, pixelWidth:1936, pixelHeight:2592
...
```

Everything looks great at first, but then for the 6th image (with local identifier value `6B4B893A-E517-452D-972C-82354D93EA1C/L0/001`) it cuts off and formats incorrectly.  In this case only the timestamp cut off, but in other examples such as:

```
...
2018-01-08 11:30:43.573010-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:DACB34B1-59B0-4CFE-BB40-E39AEB507E0F/L0/001, creationD2018-01-08 11:30:43.573032-0500 testapp[83752:9722498] localIdentifier:38C58C59-41B8-4240-AAAB-B7C2A7C10B34/L0/001, creationDate:Fri Mar  1 19:01:23 2013, pixelWidth:2448, pixelHeight:3264
...
```

The log statement itself is cutoff/overwritten with the next statement.

Comment: All `NSLog()` messages should go to the system console, take a look at the system log directly; e.g. using the `Console` app, or a good text editor if the OS allows it; to see if that offers any clues?

Comment: May be bug in NSLog. Is it so principal?